# Log4j2 Displaying Different Time than System's Time

Tags: java, log4j2

Im'm using Log4j2 with the following configuration:

```
# Logs Appender

rootLogger.level = INFO
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = fileLogger

appender.file.type = RollingFile
appender.file.name = fileLogger
appender.file.fileName = filename.log
appender.file.filePattern = filename_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log
appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern = %d [%-15.15t] %-5p %-30.30c{1} - %m%n

# Rotate log file each day
appender.file.policies.type = Policies
appender.file.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.file.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.file.policies.time.modulate = true

# Delete files older than 30 days
appender.file.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.file.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.file.strategy.delete.basePath = ${logsPath}
appender.file.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 1
appender.file.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
appender.file.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 30d
```

The log time and system time differ by one hour.

For the system time

```
$ date
Tue Oct 23 11:35:31 WEST 2018
```

Produces the log time

```
2018-10-23 10:35:31,922 [qtp380231503-47] INFO
```

This issue only happening in one server. Info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux alfriptvappstest01 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Apr 11 17:27:00 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

On other servers and my development machine it's displaying the time correctly.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like a time zone issue.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the layout of your appender in order to display the timezone, or to force a particular one. For instance:

%d{ISO8601} instead of %d

More info at:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html